# Draw attention to a changed default

Tags: indicator

I've got a medium-sized form with a radio buttons field with two options (hereinafter "radio-button field") as one of the first fields.
Down the form, there's a numeric field (hereinafter "numeric field") with a default value, that can be edited by the user.
The default value of the numeric field changes according to the radio-button field at the top.

**My concern:** A user might see the default value, rely on it, then change the radio-button field above - and miss the fact the default value was changed below.

**The question:** What is the best way to indicate such a change to the user?

I want it to be emphasised enough for him to notice, but also subtle enough because most of the times it will be as expected and I don't want too much attention to it.

Comment: Is selection of one of the "radio-button field[s]" required?

Comment: "Down the form..." — Is there a reason the "radio-button field" and it's corresponding "numeric field" are not next to each other?

Comment: Thx for your questions. (1) All fields are required. (2) Users won't expect the fields to be related. They will expect the first field to be on top and the other at the bottom, each of them have other fields that are more related

Comment: How are the fields related? Is there a calculation? If so display the calculated value next to each of the fields so when one is changed the calculation near each input changes. — It appears cognitively the fields are connected but apparently must be separate. This makes the interface more complex but if necessary for users to effectively use the form then so be it.

Comment: So, how about displaying the corresponding value next to each of the fields so when one is changed the displayed value of the other input is updated accordingly?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I understand you're suggestion completely. Let me just mention, that I'm currently thinking that the obvious thing will be to write "Updated!" next to the changed field, or color it differently - but that could be problematic if the user notices it after a long while. So, currently, before fully understanding your suggestion, I think about showing a short toast message "Field X was changed". And, again, thx for your help, it's really not obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Show a [toast message](https://uxmovement.com/forms/best-practices-to-make-your-toasts-usable-and-accessible/) that will disappear after a while